# ViewModel in Class project

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, icommand

I'm building a WPF application which is based on the MVVM pattern.

Later on we are going to build a Silverlight application of the same type, and also a Web application.

I want to use my ViewModels in all three UI:s, so my idea was to move the vm:s to a class library, but then I lost my ICommands, is there an easy way to get around this?

How would solve this problem?

Best regards, 
Peter Larsson!

Answer (score 0):

MVVM assumes WPF/SilverLight's binding so you would not be able to use it on a web for sure, neither it is appropriate - it would be hopeless without binding.

MVVM is nothing but MVP while you need MVC on the web.

Comment: Ok, lets forget about the web for a moment. For my Silverlight application, is there a way to use the same ModelView classes in separate project and still have my ICommands intact?

Comment: I believe in SilverLight 4.0 yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move all your domain-specific logic not in to the ViewModels, but the Model.  The ViewModel is just a View of your Model.  It handle's the UI logic in your app, which may be specific to Silverlight, WPF or Web.  What should never change between implementations is the Model - the core of your domain.

Put the logic in the Model, then use M-V-VM for the WPF and Silverlight implementations, and MVC for the web implementation.